# jQuery onclick SVG ID doesn't show alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have this SVG animation and clicking on the ID should activate an alert. Unfortunately nothing happens and the console shows no errors regarding this code.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".overlay #medical").on('click', function () {
            console.log('testing - click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]
Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried to used this selector instead `"#medical"`? (I think JQuery optimizes for ids but I'm not sur)

Comment: It seems to be an SVG related issue, since jQuery overrall and actions on other ID's work fine.

Comment: Try setting body.click function, and check event , see what do you have for target when you click your svg button

Comment: Are you able to put an  'onclick' on your <g> tag? If you can try something like this: <g onclick=''showAlert(id)" ...>

<script>
function showAlert(g){
    alert('test');
}
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following code:

```
    var anim;
    var elem = document.getElementById('bodymovin')
    var animData = {
        container: elem,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        rendererSettings: {
            progressiveLoad: false
        },
        path: 'data_large.json'
    };
    anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);

    var lookingForLinks = true;
    setTimeout(addLinksToSvgAnim, 1000);

    function addLinksToSvgAnim() {
        if (lookingForLinks) {
            let medicalG = document.getElementById("medical");
            let foodG = document.getElementById("food");
            let collabG = document.getElementById("collab");
            let volunteersG = document.getElementById("volunteers");
            let projectsG = document.getElementById("projects");

            if (medicalG && foodG && volunteersG && projectsG) {
                lookingForLinks = false;
                medicalG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/medical-aid";
                });
                foodG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/humanitarian-aid";
                });
                collabG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/our-story/partners";
                });
                volunteersG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/get-involved";
                });
                projectsG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/bringhope-projects";
                });
            }
            setTimeout(addLinksToSvgAnim, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not (currently) fully support SVG. You should instead use native JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('medical').addEventListener('click',function() {
    console.log('testing - click');
},false);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. Unfortunately no change. You can check the animation here: bringhope.info > click on globe and wait till the end.

Comment: @user3615851 [It works](https://jsfiddle.net/j71va6z7/), you must have something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Any suggestions where to go from here? Stuck at this for ages

Comment: Many (most?) jQuery methods do not work in SVGs. [However event handlers do work just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/j71va6z7/1/).